# How can I use the output from pwd as a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, pwd

My homework question given is:

> How can you print the path of the current directory (working
> directory) and how can you use it as a variable?

The first part of the question is easily answered: By using [pwd](/questions/tagged/pwd).

But how can I use the output as a variable?

Comment: Have a look at the defined environment variables (hint: use `env` to print them). Or initialize your own variable with the output of `pwd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, you can execute a command and obtain the output using backticks, for example

```
paul@paul-laptop:~$ WORKING_DIRECTORY=`pwd`
paul@paul-laptop:~$ echo $WORKING_DIRECTORY
/home/paul
```

There is an alternate syntax too, using a dollar sign and brackets - `WORKING_DIRECTORY=$(pwd)`

Answer (score 5):

Bash has a variable `PWD` which should be preferred over the `pwd` command:

```
echo "$PWD"
```

Comment: `pwd` is a Bash builtin so the cost is low.